# Regex Conditional Matching for escaped chars

Tags: regex

I am parsing incoming data.

And it looks like this:

```
"Hello there are \"quotations\" that i wanna ignore" "other data I don't want"

"Selected this"  "other data I don't want"
```

As of now I am using

```
^"[^\n]+?"
```

But it only grabs   `"Hello there are \"`
How do i give it a condition that its a " with out a \ preceding it?

I need a Regex that will Grab the first "quoted part but not the other data"

Tried `preg_match('/^"[^\n]+?[^\\]"/', $lines,$name);`

Oh for PHP i used `/^"[^\n]+?[^\\\\]"/`

Comment: What if you have `"Hello \\"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify that the character before the closing quote is not a backslash:

```
^"[^\n]+?[^\\]"
```

Comment: Do you have any links to negative lookbacks?

Comment: @CrisG changed it to make it even simpler

Comment: Oh yes that makes a lot of sense, but now look backs are something very interesting?

Comment: They're called a "look behind" or a "look ahead" (or collectively, "look arounds"). Read about them [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). They are definitely worth learning.

Comment: I've been on 999 regex upvotes all day. One more to get the regex gold badge. The suspense is killing me!

Comment: @TimPietzcker Long time no see! The 1000th vote from a true regex guru - how fitting :)

Comment: Warning: preg_match() [<a href='function.preg-match'>function.preg-match</a>]: Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class at offset 14 .... Why am i getting that error

preg_match('/^"[^\n]+?[^\\]"/', $lines,$name);

Comment: I mean I can't vote for a moderator who hasn't got a regex gold badge, now can I?

Comment: @CrisG: You need two backslashes inside the character class.

Comment: @CrisG did you try double backslash, like in my code?

Comment: Yes, but for some reason the comment is taking it out. Check Question at the bottom.

Comment: I found the answer, you have to escape the escape char .

Comment: @CrisG yes four backslashes in a string literal turns into two backslahses in the string, turns into 1 backslash inside the regex.